# Customize converter message to include input with bolded invalid characters

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, converters, message

Mojarra 2.1.29

Consider the standard `javax.faces.Integer` converter. If we enter an invalid number we'll recieve the message:

> 'foo' must be a number consisting of one or more digits

I need to customize the message as follows if the number contains invalid charaters, print the input along with bolded invalid charaters. For instance 1234add

> The number contains invalid charaters: 1234**add**

I think it's not possible to just define my own custom properties file containing the message as follows:

```
javax.faces.converter.BigIntegerConverter.BIGINTEGER={2}: ''{0}'' must be a number consisting of one or more digits.
```

Do I have to write my own custom converter that is a subclass of the `javax.faces.Integer`?

Is it possible to customize the error-message in such a way without writing a custom converter?

Comment: I think, It's not an offtopic, because the question is about standard converter's capability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. It's only hacky for two reasons:

- Formatting logic is been encapsulated in EL instead of in a reusable Java class (although you could create a special tagfile to prevent copypasting over all place in case you intend to reuse same logic elsewhere).
- HTML is needed in faces message while `<h:message>` doesn't support unescaping HTML (so a `<h:outputText>` which manually grabs the message is needed to display the message).

Here it is:

```html
<h:inputText binding="#{input}"
    converter="javax.faces.Integer" 
    converterMessage="The number contains invalid charaters: #{input.submittedValue.replaceAll('(\\d*)?(\\D+)(\\d*)?', '$1&lt;b&gt;$2&lt;/b&gt;$3')}" />
<h:outputText id="messageForInput" value="#{facesContext.getMessageList(input.clientId)[0].summary}" escape="false" />
```

Note the importance of `binding` pointing to a local variable rather than a bean property.

#### See also:

- [How do I add HTML code to JSF FacesMessage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195348/how-do-i-add-html-code-to-jsf-facesmessage/)
- [Render JSF h:message with p element instead of span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19730562/render-jsf-hmessage-with-p-element-instead-of-span/)
- [How does the 'binding' attribute work in JSF? When and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911158/how-does-the-binding-attribute-work-in-jsf-when-and-how-should-it-be-used)

Comment: __Formatting logic is been encapsulated in EL__ I tried to just insert the <span> tag into a FacesMessage as follows: `new FacesMessage("The number contains invalid charaters: <span style:\"font-weight: bold\">emphasized chars</span>"` But the `<>` charaters were replaced with `&lt&rt` correspondingly. Is that what you meant? I do that within my custom converter and then throw ConverterExpcetion fot that message.

Comment: No. That's covered by second part. JSF by default escapes HTML coming from variables as part of builtin XSS attack prevention. You'd need to explicitly unescape it and that's with the standard JSF component set only possible with `<h:outputText>`.